# How to make sure the previous session.send() is complete before sending more data in reactor-netty WebSocketSession

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am creating a WebSocket Server using spring-webflux and reactor-netty, and on every connection, I get a WebSocketSession (with ReactorNettyWebSocketSession instance). Suppose I store all the sessions in a map and want to send some messages to this WebSocketSessions based on some business logic, I can do something like

```
            Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.fromIterable(messages);
            for (WebSocketSession session : sessions.values()) {
                if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session
                            .send(stringFlux.map(session::textMessage))
                            .subscribe();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("session is closed.. skipping.. " + session.getId());
                    sessions.remove(session.getId());
                }
            }
```

Now, when I send messages to the session, is there a way to make sure that the session's previous send is complete? If a client is very slow and/or not reading from the server, it can create memory overhead for the server if the server keeps writing to the socket when the client is not reading or reading very slowly.

How to get a callback or some mechanism in which I can prevent writing to the WebSocketSession/socket if the client is slow?

Comment: You can use `concatMap` with prefetch set to 0 in order to achieve that. Will not work with your code as it is thought. Consider making the session values a Flux as well.

Comment: @Khepu, sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean something like `Flux.fromIterable(sessions.values()).concatMap(f->{}, 0).doSomethingMore()`? I am very new to reactor and reactor-netty. So, a bigger explanation will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of assumptions behind this answer so we might need to discuss the details in the comments. The idea is that the following code sends messages one by one for each session, but concurrently for all sessions. You can tweak this according to your needs, turning `concatMap` to `flatMap` will enable concurrent sending while turning `flatMap` to `concatMap` will ensure that all all messages have to be sent to a single session before moving on to the next one.

```java
Flux.fromIterable(sessions.values())
    .filter(session -> session.isOpen()) // keep open sessions
    .doOnDsicard(Session.class, session -> {
        System.out.println("session is closed.. skipping.. " + session.getId());
        sessions.remove(session.getId());
    })
    // flatMap here will allow the messages to be sent to each session concurrently
    .flatMap(session -> Flux.fromIterable(messages) 
        .map(session::textMessage)
        // concatMap here will force messages to be sent one by one (per session)
        .concatMap(message -> Mono
            .fromCallable(() -> session
                .send(Mono.just(message))), 0))
```

Comment: This code seems to be solving the issue from pure "react" way of sending a flux of messages to a flux sessions, but still it doesn't work. session.send(...) doesn't actually send the message to the underlying WebSocketSession/Socket unless the .subscribe() is call on that Mono returned by session.send(...). My concern is mainly on slow clients who don't read or read fast and and how to make sure that before I do another session.send(...), the previous write was successful. Thanks for your answer though. It gave more clarity of react constructs.

Comment: @Amudhan Using subscribe there would be problematic, just remove the Mono.fromCallable and things should work just fine! This would be the last piece required to actually achieve what you want. If you call subscribe then a "background process" is essentially spawned and that is why it will not wait for the sending to be completed right now